# How to change Pagination from 'per page' to only first and last pages?

Tags: php, html, pagination

i have a code for my table  pagination.
but now i have a problem. the pagination is showing EVERY page. but i got over 900 pages.

ALSO: i need to use PDO

i want the pagination to work like this:

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qnsEc.png)

i dont know how to make this in my already excisting code:

```
        $per_page_html = '';
        $page = 1;
        $start=0;
        if(!empty($_POST["page"])) {
            $page = $_POST["page"];
            $start=($page-1) * ROW_PER_PAGE;
        }
        $limit=" limit " . $start . "," . ROW_PER_PAGE;
        $pagination_statement = $oConn->prepare($sql);
        $pagination_statement->execute();

        $row_count = $pagination_statement->rowCount();
        if(!empty($row_count)){
            $per_page_html .= "<div style='text-align:center;margin:20px 0px;'>";
            $page_count=ceil($row_count/ROW_PER_PAGE);
            if($page_count>1) {
                for($i=1;$i<=$page_count;$i++){
                    if($i==$page){
                        $per_page_html .= '<input type="submit" name="page" value="' . $i . '" class="btn-page current" />';
                    } else {
                        $per_page_html .= '<input type="submit" name="page" value="' . $i . '" class="btn-page" />';
                    }
                }
            }
            $per_page_html .= "</div>";
        }

        $query = $sql.$limit;
        $pdo_statement = $oConn->prepare($query);
        $pdo_statement->execute();
        $result = $pdo_statement->fetchAll();
```

Comment: See this tutorial it has what you need : https://phppot.com/php/php-pagination/

Comment: ROW_PER_PAGE 10 is your page limit.! it should be on top of your page as define variable, or you can use limit 10;

Comment: @Dilek  i know i have 
define("ROW_PER_PAGE",10);  Set

Comment: @Dilek the link you send is not much help for me, i have to make everything with PDO.. can i still use the link?

Comment: So you need a solution to be able to navigate to 1st page and last page ?

Comment: @Lisa-x is that search result page ? or a normal page ? I was on mobile couldnt write codes :)

Answer (score 1):

I dont see your table and your query in your question so I will give 2 complete examples tested on my demo site, you need to change it to your own variables.

**Solution 1.**

Here is the example pagination for items belong to a category, for **simple pagination** :

```
$perpage = "3";
//This limit of the page to show on each page
$n_stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM categories");
$n_stmt->execute(); 
$total_posts = $n_stmt->rowCount();
$total_pages = ceil($total_posts/$perpage);
$page = !empty($_GET['page']) && $_GET['page'] ? (int) $_GET['page'] : 1;
if($page < 1) $page = 1;
if($page > $total_pages) $page = $total_pages;
$limit = ($page - 1) * $perpage;
$pag_limit = 10;
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM categories ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT :limit, :perpage");
$stmt->bindValue(":limit",$limit, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindValue(":perpage",$perpage, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();
while($news = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
 // Do what ever you want here

}
```

And pagination:

```
<div class="pagination">
<?php   if($page >1){?>
    <a href="category/page/1">First</a>
    <a href="category/page/<?php echo $page - 1;?>">Preview</a>

    <?php } for($i = $page - $pag_limit; $i < $page + $pag_limit + 1; $i++){ 
        if($i > 0 and $i <= $total_pages){
            if($i == $page){?>
                <a href="category/page/<?php echo $i;?>" class="active"><?php echo $i;?></a>
            <?php }else{?>
            <a href="category/page/<?php echo $i;?>"><?php echo $i;?></a>
            <?php   
            }
        }
    ?>

    <?php } ?>

    <?php if($page != $total_pages){?>
    <a href="category/page/<?php echo $page + 1;?>">next</a>
    <a href="category/page/<?php echo $total_pages;?>">Last</a>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

**Solution 2.**

**Here is pagination for search result with your codes**, as I said this code works on my demo site you need to change your own variables and its in pdo:

```
define("ROW_PER_PAGE",10);
//this goes on top of your page

require_once("db.php");  
    $search_keyword = '';
    if(!empty($_POST['search']['keyword'])) {
        $search_keyword = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($_POST["search"]["keyword"]), ENT_QUOTES);
    }
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM posts WHERE title LIKE :keyword OR descriptions LIKE :keyword OR subject LIKE :keyword ORDER BY id DESC ';

    /* Pagination Code starts */
    $per_page_html = '';
    $page = 1;
    $start=0;
    if(!empty($_POST["page"])) {
        $page = $_POST["page"];
        $start=($page-1) * ROW_PER_PAGE;
    }
    $limit=" limit " . $start . "," . ROW_PER_PAGE;
    $pagination_statement = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $pagination_statement->bindValue(':keyword', '%' . $search_keyword . '%', PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $pagination_statement->execute();

    $row_count = $pagination_statement->rowCount();
    if(!empty($row_count)){
        $per_page_html .= "<div class=\"pagination\">";
        $page_count=ceil($row_count/ROW_PER_PAGE);
        if($page_count>1) {
            for($i=1;$i<=$page_count;$i++){
                if($i==$page){
                    $per_page_html .= "<input type=\"submit\" name=\"page\" value=" . $i . " class=\"btn-page current\" />";
                } else {
                    $per_page_html .= "<input type=\"submit\" name=\"page\" value=" . $i . " class=\"btn-page\"/>";
                }
            }
        }
        $per_page_html .= "</div>";
    }

    $query = $sql.$limit;
    $pdo_statement = $pdo->prepare($query);
    $pdo_statement->bindValue(":keyword", "%" . $search_keyword . "%", PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $pdo_statement->execute();
    $result = $pdo_statement->fetchAll();
```

Your html part with pagination at the bottom and your result in form same as you can see

```
<form name="frmSearch" action="search/" method="post">
<div class="searchf">
<input type="text" name="search[keyword]" class="field" value="<?php echo $search_keyword; ?>" id="keyword" maxlength="25">
<input type="submit" name="submit" class="searchf-btn" value="Ara">
</div>
    <?php
    if(!empty($result)) { 
        foreach($result as $row) {
    ?>
    <div class="news_box">
    <a href="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($row["news_url"]);?>/" title="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($row["title"]);?>">
        <div class="title"><h2><?php echo htmlspecialchars($row["title"]);?></h2></div>
        <div class="image">
        <img src="images/posts/<?php echo htmlspecialchars($row["img"]);?>" alt="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($row["title"]);?>"/></div>
        <div class="spot"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($row["subject"]);?></div>
    </a>
    </div>
    <?php
        }
    }
    ?>
<div class="cl">&nbsp;</div>
//Here is pagination
<?php echo $per_page_html; ?>
</form>
```

I am using seo urls in demo, you need to set htaccess for links, or change pagination links like so : `your_page.php?page=$i`.

Both tested on my demo site and working, I used some filtering functions you can remove them.

Comment: i tried the second code the one with the search. but i still get 900 pages....would it be easier if i shared the whole page?

Comment: @Lisa-x strange, I only get 10 `define("ROW_PER_PAGE",10);` you must be doing something wrong or changing code or removing limitation. define should be at the very first of everything in your page.

Comment: im sorry i wasnt clear maybe. i get 10 rows per page. only i have 900 pages in the bottom from $per_page_html;. this is the issue. i need something like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qnsEc.png

Comment: @Lisa-x is that search result page or what its ? if not a search result page try the solution 1 and remove pagination except next and preview

Comment: no its not a search result page. its a datatable that i loaded in. with many many rows

Comment: @Lisa-x datatables has their own paginations, you should add all your datatable and php codes and clear your question if you are using ajax or js or bootstrap. Anyway this is your solution in answer  **simple pagination** in answer. second solution is for a search page you need to use my first solution which is **simple pagination**